# Converting data to PDF on iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, pdf

Let us say I have an application that has a bunch of text and image data. It there a way to then convert the strings and images within my application into PDF format which I could then email?

What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: google search reveals many many links on how to do this. Might be worth doing a modicum of research before asking the community a "how do I?" question

Comment: In my defense I don't think this question was too unreasonable. Often times the solutions I find on google lead me down incorrect paths. Is it so harmful to get some feedback here first? Isn't that the whole point of this forum?

Comment: Along these same lines I think it would be more appropriate to vote to close rather then vote down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such a general question, it's hard to answer with anything that isn't more or less a repetition of what Apple's docs say: [Generating PDF Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html)

Answer (score 1):

Apple's support docs are pretty good on this.  The gist of it is you want to create a pdf graphics context CGPDFContext and then draw to it.  The wierdest thing is that you have to flip the y axis on your drawings to PDF because iOS and Core Graphics use different origins for the axis.  All this is explained in the apple docs though.  If you have any specific questions, I'm new to developing and stack overflow, but I'd be happy to help you out.
If you want to see how my app writes PDF, check out Photo Logger in the app store.